# Front end for Executing Selenium Test Automation

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver, testng

I have created a Selenium Test web automaton program using TestNG.The problem we face is Whenever we need to execute test cases we need to open eclipse and open file TestNG.xml -> Right Click -> Run as TestNG Suite

We are planning to create a front end to execute test cases and we are planning to remove TestNG Dependency. How can we develop the front end and how to execute the test case any ideas.
Any suggestions will be appreciable.

Comment: Could you explain a bit more about your requirement. What do you mean by front-end? Do you intend to execute automation script from a web page ?

Comment: @Ayaz yes sir something like that but that we don't know how to execute java file from server resides at local machine....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understood your question correctly, you can try to use CI services (e.g. Jenkins) or configure some plan. Also you can configure there custom variables and execution schedule.
https://jenkins.io/